# VBSCRIPT arrays keys

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I'm fairly new to vbscript and I'm struggling a little as I'm more familiar with Javascript. 
Can someone please give me a hand?

Does vbscript allow the use of named array keys like I have in my example below?

For example I have:

```
Dim result(3)
result(age)       = 60
result(firstname) = "Tony"
result(height)    = 187
result(weight)    = 76

msgbox("Age: "    & result(age)       & vbCr &_
       "Name: "   & result(firstname) & vbCr &_
       "Height: " & result(height)    & vbCr &_
       "Weight: " & result(weight)    )
```

The resulting msgbox shows:

```
  Age: 76 
  Name: 76 
  Height: 76 
  Weight: 76
```

This seems to assign *every* element in the result array to 76, which 
should only be assigned to the "weight" element.

Is this happening because vbscript only accepts integers as the key/ 
index for arrays?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks 
Turgs

Comment: Incidentally, the reason you were getting 76 is because all of your "keys" are being interpreted as undefined variables, **which are evaluated as zero with no warning**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to [Andrew's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372001/vbscript-arrays-keys/1372058#1372058) on this page, I've been able to use the Dictionary object in VBScript to do what I was after using a syntax more like Associative Arrays normall use in other languages:

```
Dim result 
Set result = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary") 

result("age") = 60 
result("firstname") = "Tony" 
result("height") = 187 
result("weight") = 76 
    
msgbox("Age: "       & result("age")       & vbCr &_ 
      "First Name: " & result("firstname") & vbCr &_ 
      "Height: "     & result("height")    & vbCr &_ 
      "Weight: "     & result("weight")    )
```

More information on the dictionary object can be found here:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/guide/sas_scr_ildk.mspx

I hope that's helpful to others trying to do the same thing.

Thanks to [Richard Mueller](http://www.rlmueller.net/) for providing this solution via the *microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript* Usenet group.

Answer (score 10):

In order to acheive this, you need to use a Dictionary object from the Scripting library:-

```
Dim result : Set result = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
result.Add "Age", 60
result.Add "Name", "Tony"
```

and so on. You can retrieve items as:-

```
Dim age : age = result("Age")
```

However, if you have fixed set of identifiers you might consider defining a class:-

```
Class CResult
    Public Age
    Public Name
End Class

Dim result : Set result = new CResult
result.Age = 60
result.Name = "Tony"

MsgBox "Age: "    & result.Age       & vbCrLf & _
   "Name: "   & result.Nname) & vbCrLf
```

By the way, typically, we use CR LF for new lines not just CR. Also, if you are using a method or function as a statement (as in the MsgBox above) don't enclose parameters in ( ).

Answer (score 0):

No VBScript only allows for an integer index. That being said you could declare integer constants to deliver the functionality you're wanting.

If you want a named array (like the example above) then you'll probably need some kind of dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

OP's code was can actually be made to work with a complete hack. This is important as some older coder's have used this approach and it might help to learn this hack.

So to get the following "identifiers" to work, i.e. age/firstname/height/weight:

```
result(age)
result(firstname) 
result(height)  
result(weight)
```

The hack is to define these as variables or global variables to the correctly ordered indices. And of course that can be done programmatically:

```
'Creates variables that map the field name to its position in the Array.
Private Sub CreateArrayIdentifiersAsGlobalVariables(fieldNames)
    Dim globalVariablesToCreate
    Dim fieldNameIndex
    fieldNameIndex = 0
    For Each fieldName In fieldNames
        If Len(fieldName) > 0 Then
            globalVariablesToCreate = globalVariablesToCreate & "fieldName & "=" & fieldNameIndex & vbCrLf
            fieldNameIndex = fieldNameIndex + 1
        End If
    Next
    Execute globalVariablesToCreate
End Sub
```

Where "fieldNames" would be an Array of all the string fieldNames.

So you would call that function with the Array "age, firstname, height, weight". And then, for example, you would get "age" as a global variable evaluation to the integer 0, and firstname as 1, then "result(age)" and "result(firstname)" would work as expected.